# How to close fancybox within an ajax popup with another version of jquery loaded?

Tags: ajax, fancybox, jquery

I am having an issue closing a fancybox popup when jquery is included within the popup page (i'm using AJAX and including an external php page within the popup). The fancybox is setup as follows:

```
$(".various3").fancybox({
'type'    : 'ajax',
'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
'transitionIn'      : 'none',
'transitionOut'     : 'none',
'ajax' : {
type        : 'GET'
}
});
```

The popup has a 'Cancel' button to allow users to close the popup (using jQuery.fancybox.close();). I have to include jquery within the popup page to allow some other functionality to work and this prevents the jQuery.fancybox.close();  from working. If i remove jquery from the popup page then it works fine, however I cannot work out how to reference the instance of jquery on the main page (i have tried parent in case, although i wouldn't have thought this should work as it's a div and indeed it didn't). I have tried using:

```
var localjquery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

within the popup page and this allows me to use jQuery.fancybox.close(); to close the popup successfully however this prevents the use of $ to reference jquery which is needed for other plugins on this page that i can't edit. If I add

```
var mainjquery = jQuery.noConflict();
```

after the first instance of jquery on the main page then this obviously works fine and i can refer to it as mainjquery on the parent, but if then try

```
mainjquery.fancybox.close();
```

on the popup it says mainjquery is undefined.

I suspect it's a problem due to a combination of multiple jquery instances and loading a completely separate page via ajax into a div (rather than using an iframe etc whereby i could then use parent. or similar). If anyone could shed any light on how I could reference the mainjquery reference from the child popup, or a better way I can close the fancybox then that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much!

Dave

Comment: try also adding fancybox inside the page that is loaded via ajax so when you run `$.fancybox.close();` it will use the fancybox tied up to the version of jQuery on that page. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do is test to see if it is an ajax request, and if so don't include the jquery (or any other scripts you already have for that matter).

Here's a sample of code I use on my php pages for doing both ajax and regular page requests.

```
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
....
if(!IS_AJAX)
{
    //echo your header with scripts
    echo $header;
}
//else just echo the contents of the page body
```

edit:

If you need to add things to the `head` tag, you should be using an iframe instead of an ajax type for the fancybox.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response! The problem is I need to include scripts on the popup page for other functionality to work which is why i'm including jquery plus other scripts again (and defining new headers etc). I have just realised that I actually made a mistake and my code above does work as long as I define var localjquery = jQuery.noConflict(true); in the popup. I guess doing this ensures $ reverts to the original jquery instance and then it uses that. What is strange is that it doesn't work without this and doing it this way presumably means i'm actually loading it twice unecessarily?

Comment: If you need to add stuff to the `head` you should probably be loading the page in an iframe. There's no real savings using ajax when you're just fetching the entire page anyway.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, thanks for your help. Out of interest do you know why you can't access the parent version of jquery without reloading jquery and running localjquery = jQuery.noConflict(true) in the ajax popup? This is not a problem for this case but is just to ensure a better understanding of it all? Thanks :)

Comment: `jQuery.noConflict(true)` says it will work with multiple versions of jQuery, but you may need to call that BEFORE you make your ajax call. You would probably have to rewrite all of your current code to use the localjquery variable instead.